# How does ARP protocol really work

Tags: networking, routing, arp

I know that if a destination host is in the other network the returned MAC address is the MAC of the router instead of the designed host. I wonder now how does it function. If my assumption is right that when the sender sends a ARP broadcast the router check if the destination host is in the LAN and if so forwards the broadcast message into the LAN hosts and if not (the destination host is outside of the LAN) the router answers with his own MAC not broadcasting the message to the LAN avoiding unnecessary network traffic?

Comment: *"if the destination host is in the LAN and if so forwards the broadcast message into the LAN hosts"* -- Apparently you first need to learn what a "broadcast" is, and how switches work.  IOW your assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work as you describe. Think of Ethernet LANs as divided into segments, where each host on a segment can talk to each other host on the segment. (That was how Ethernet originally worked, before everyone moved to point-to-point connections with switches). So one segment looks like this:

```
          <--- 192.168.3.0/24  --->
   ---------------------------------------------------    
      |                |             |            |
    Router          Host 1        Host 2       Host 3
    192.168.3.254   192.168.3.1  192.168.3.2  192.168.3.3
      |
... ----
```

The *netmask* describes the allowed range of IP addresses on this segment, in this case 192.168.3.0 to 192.168.3.255.

Now let's look at Host 1. It's network adapter will have address `192.168.3.1/24`, so can distinguish IP addresses on the LAN from other addresses. It will also have a catchall routing entry that just says "use 192.168.3.254 as gateway for every other IP".

So when it sends a packet so some IP address, it will know which "local" IP address on the LAN to use, either directly one of the local Hosts, or the Router with the gateway address.

Next it looks up this IP in the local ARP cache. If the IP address is not in the cache, no matter if its the Router IP address or another Host IP address, and sends an Ethernet Broadcast over the LAN with contents "hello, I have MAC address 00:11:22:33:44:55, I'm looking for the MAC address of IP 192.168.3.x". And the box (router or host) with the IP address of 192.168.3.x answers "hello 00:11:22:33:44:55, I have the MAC address 66:77:88:99:AA:BB, and I'm the owner of IP address 192.168.3.x".

That's all that happens.

Comment: I'm not so sure You are right with the last paragraph. Look below on my conversation with Zoredache. I've suggested that if the destination address isn't on the LAN the sender asks the router directly not using broadcast message, but just unicast so the sender takes the decision whether to send the broadcast to the LAN or unicast just to the router.

Comment: If the destination address is not on the LAN, you can't reach it directly via the MAC address, so using ARP makes no sense. If you don't believe, fire up Wireshark and watch what happens. Alternatively, use `arp` to see which addresses are cached. You won't see an address that's not directly reachable on LAN or WLAN.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand me. I know that i cannot reach non LAN MAC, but I've asked if i'm right that in the case of non LAN destination the sender sends unicast ARP request  directly to the def. gateway to get 's MAC...

Comment: On L2 OSI (Ethernet packets), you send unicasts to a known MAC address (IP addresses don't exist on that level). So you could send a unicast ARP request only to the gateway if you knew its MAC address. But if you knew its MAC address, you don't need the ARP request, because the whole point of the ARP request is to find the MAC address for a given IP address. So no, there's no such thing as a "unicast ARP request" - it makes no sense. You *do* get unicast ARP **replies** - because the MAC address of the requester is known. Which doesn't keep other hosts from updateing their ARP cache, however.

Comment: Sorry but i'm still in doubt. How can You explain Zoredache answer that " If the destination is on the local network, which is determined by the local ip and mask, then the computer will try to arp directly for the destination address. If the destination is not on the local network, and a matching route is found, then the computer will arp for the gateway address defined in the route" which suggests that the sender makes a decision while Your answer suggests that it's not the case.

Comment: *Sigh*. I give up. Just run Wireshark and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An arp is not sent to the router, and arp is sent to the entire network.  The router, or any host may reply.

> I know that if a destination host is in the other network the returned MAC address is the MAC of the router instead of the designed host. I wonder now how does it function.

Your computer will look at its local routing table.  If the destination is on the local network, which is determined by the local ip and mask, then the computer will try to arp directly for the destination address.  If the destination is not on the local network, and a matching route is found, then the computer will arp for the gateway address defined in the route.

Comment: So if the destination is on the local network the message passes (physically) through the router but only the switch part (layer) of the router is being used to broadcast the ARP request?

Comment: @Mulligan That depends a lot on how the network is set up and we have no idea how that would be. Typical SoHo routers include a switch that connects wired traffic on the local network. If both devices are plugged into the LAN ports on such a router, then ARP queries and responses for those devices will pass through the switch portion of the router.

Comment: @Zoredache So am i right that if the destination is on the local network the sending host sends broadcast message to all the hosts in the LAN and if outside off the LAN sends just "normal" unicast message to the router asking it's MAC?

Comment: @Mulligan that last statement is correct 99.99% of the time, at least for Ethernet.  Keep in mind that there are other technologies then Ethernet like serial that operate differently.